# Python txt file searching not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x

The aim of the following snippet of code is to search through a text file, and look for the variable 'name'. If 'name' is present anywhere in the text file, it should set `user_new` to `False`. Otherwise, it is non-existent in the txt file, and `user_new` should be `True`.

However, user_new, in both cases, is never set to anything, and results in the error: "local variable 'user_new' referenced before assignment"

```
with open("accuracy.txt", "r") as search:
    lineno = 0
    for line in search:
        lineno = lineno + 1
        if name in line:
            user_new = False
            break
        else:
            user_new = True
            break
search.close()
print(user_new)
```

Comment: Where did you define `name`? What's its value? Also: when using `with` you don't need to close the file afterwards

Comment: name was defined by a user input earlier in the code. I can post the full code with that if required, but there's a lot of unnecessary stuff there for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way this could happen in this code is if the for loop has nothing to iterate over. This would mean the if statement is never run and `user_new` is never defined.

Make sure `accuracy.txt` has at least one line, otherwise the loop will never run as there are no lines to loop through.

If having no lines in the text file is unavoidable, consider checking the length of the file with something such as:

```
if search.read() == "":
    user_new = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was at times `accuracy.txt` was empty, which caused the loop to never run and `user_new` to never be defined. Thanks to @Joe Allen for the answer.